# How do I remove the error in vue create?

Tags: npm

I am new to vuejs and vuetify. First I ran the command npm install @vue/cli -g. Then I ran the command vue create test. And I am getting this error:

```
C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\vue-templat
e-compiler\index.js:10
  throw new Error(
  ^

Error:

Vue packages version mismatch:

- vue@2.5.17 (C:\Users\Dell\node_modules\vue\dist\vue.runtime.common.js)
- vue-template-compiler@2.6.10 (C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@
vue\cli\node_modules\vue-template-compiler\package.json)

This may cause things to work incorrectly. Make sure to use the same version for
 both.
If you are using vue-loader@>=10.0, simply update vue-template-compiler.
If you are using vue-loader@<10.0 or vueify, re-installing vue-loader/vueify sho
uld bump vue-template-compiler to the latest.

   at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\c
li\node_modules\vue-template-compiler\index.js:10:9)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\c
li\node_modules\vue-jscodeshift-adapter\src\parse-sfc.js:1:18)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
```

Earlier I was running the same command to make vuetify projects. Then there were no errors. So now how do I create a new project in vuetify?

Comment: Mods, can I suggest moving this question over to StackOverflow. I think it is more suitable and will get more visibility there

Comment: Yeah I was surprised to see it here. Will add it myself if this is then moved let me know and will close mine as duplicated.

Comment: here it is, feel free to edit it to improve it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58531851/vue-create-throws-vue-packages-version-mismatch-error/58531860#58531860

Answer (score 2):

If you accidentally installed `vue` package in your user's directory (`C:\Users\Dell`), then try to **remove `node_modules` directory** there ( `C:\Users\Dell\node_modules` ).

`node_modules` directory is usually created by `npm` or `yarn` command.

How was the version mismatch cuased? It looks like your packages are loaded from different locations:

- vue@2.5.17 (**C:\Users\Dell\node_modules\vue**\dist\vue.runtime.common.js)
- vue-template-compiler@2.6.10 (**C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@
  vue**\cli\node_modules\vue-template-compiler\package.json)

References:

- https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/4394
- https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/61200/vue-create-%e3%81%a7vue-packages-version-mismatch%e3%81%ae%e3%82%a8%e3%83%a9%e3%83%bc%e3%81%8c%e3%81%a7%e3%82%8b?answertab=active#tab-top (Japanese Stack Overflow)

Answer (score 1):

Following worked for me:

```
npm install vue
```

The above command showed + vue@2.6.10

Edit the file C:\Users\Dell\node_modules\vue\dist\vue.runtime.common.js. This file listed on the first line of the error above.

At line 5001 there is following line:

```
Vue$3.version = '2.5.11';
```

change that to

```
Vue$3.version = '2.6.10';
```

Then run vue create.